# Install4j is bypassing the custom installation steps

Tags: java, user-permissions, install4j

We have an application packed with install4j.
The initial step is to choose between typical and custom installations.
The custom installation is usually bringing up the option to choose the localsettings folder, the appdata folder and in the next step, the installation folder (default: Program Files).

For some reason, in a specific environment, when checking neither of the options, the installation proceeds without asking for the desired folder paths.

An error file was created as well:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: I4jScript_Internal_12
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runBooleanScript(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runBooleanScript(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runBooleanScript(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

Could you please let me know, what could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Please do not sign your questions per the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

The class that is not found is for a script in your install4j project. This can only happen if there is an inconsistency in your installation directory, i.e. if .install4j/user.jar and .install4j/i4jparams.conf are not from the same installer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The same installation worked for a few thousand times, therefore I assume that it isn't related to our side.
As for the client's side, they're trying to gain elevated permissions to the protected directories using "Run as...".

I believe it's something on the client's side, but how can we make it prompt for installation paths, after the package was already created.

Comment: @Roman After the installer has been created you cannot change anything in the installer.